# There was a conflict between two versions of an assembly when BindingRedirect supplied

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, assembly-binding-redirect

I am getting warnings when building a project about different versions of an assembly being referenced. Setting the project build output to detailed shows me the problem:

```
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

I understand that to mean that some references in some part of the solution require v1.5.0.0 and some require v1.8.0.0. Fine. We'll use 1.8.0.0 for all. So I added a binding redirect to the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.0.0" newVersion="1.8.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

But the solution still generates the same warning on build.

Should the redirect not take care of it?

Comment: Is you solution containing multiple projects? Is the warning being issued in the web project?

Comment: There are multiple projects, but the web app is the only one referencing Microsoft.ServiceBus.

Comment: is publicKeyToken case sensitive?